# Devise ajax sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, devise

I was trying to make a ajax sign_in via `devise`, I follow this [tutorial](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/).

I've successfully created a ajax `sign_up`. Here is my `registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
end
```

It works fine but fail in `sign_in`.

Here is my `session_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
end
```

The parameter and path would be like this

Path: `/users/sign_in`
Parameter:

```
{
  "user": 
  {
    "email": "123@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345678",
    "remember_me":"1"
  },
  "commit":"Log in"
}
```

But I got this error.

[image]

### Update

I still got `401 Unauthorized`. I've tried the following way.

1.Editing **application_controller.rb** the `protect_from_forgery` to `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`

2.Add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create` in **sessions_controller.rb**

3.Modify my `ajax` to this

```
$.ajax ({
      headers: {
        'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      url: "sign_in",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        "user": {"email": "example@gmail.com", "password": "password"}
      },
      success: function(msg){
        console.log("Success");
      },
      error: function(msg) {
        console.log("Errors");
      }
});
```

However, all of them threw the same error.

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-12-14 01:13:09 +0800
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"example4@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'example4@gmail.com' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CSRF token is missing... it's also stated in the tutorial you are following: http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/#maketheajaxrequests

Try editing in your `application_controller.rb` the `protect_from_forgery` to `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`

Comment: I've updated my question, I still got the `401 Unauthorized` error.